# Datatables cell contents split into 2 columns on export

Tags: jquery, datatables

Is it possible to split the contents of a cell into two columns upon export?

Example of a cells contents:

```html
2015-05-29
Open Shift
```

Open Shift

Requested output:

```html
2015-05-29 | Open Shift
```

Is this possible with Datatables?

Comment: No, you must do this serverside if you wish it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on the same issue.

You can modify a value before exporting it by using fnCellRender :  https://www.datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/button_options

I tried to add ; between my values but excel doesn't split the cell when I open the .csv file.

Here is the code I tried to split a date in 3 cells (the date is in the column 4):

```
{'sExtends':'xls',
                  "oSelectorOpts": { filter: 'applied', order: 'current' },
                  "sButtonText": "CSV Export",
                   "fnCellRender": function ( sValue, iColumn, nTr, iDataIndex ) {
                        if ( iColumn === 4 ) {
                            var dateSplit = sValue.split(".");
                            y = "20"+dateSplit[2], m = parseInt(dateSplit[1]-1), d=parseInt(dateSplit[0]);
                            return y + ";" + m + ";" + d;
                        }
                        return sValue;
                    }
                },
```

Hope it can help

**EDIT: I made it worked !!!**

change the ";" to tabulations like this: return y + '\t' + m + '\t' + d;